# node.js front end web server

Tags: node.js, webserver

I have seen lots of posts where people are recommending `nginx` or something similar as the front end web server for `node.js`.
Since node has the ability to create a web server, such as:

```
var http = require('http');
var static = require('node-static');
var file = new static.Server();
var url = require('url');

var index = require('./serverJS/index.js');
var login = require('./serverJS/login.js');
var admin_index = require('./serverJS/admin_index.js');
var admin_login = require('./serverJS/admin_login.js');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (url.parse(req.url).pathname == '/index') {
        index.serve(req, res);
    } else if (url.parse(req.url).pathname == '/login') {
        login.serve(req, res);
    } else if (url.parse(req.url).pathname == '/admin/index') {
        admin_index.serve(req, res);
    } else if (url.parse(req.url).pathname == '/admin/login') {
        admin_login.serve(req, res);
    } else {
        file.serve(req, res);
    }
}).listen(9000 , '127.0.0.1' );
```

**Q:** In what case scenario would you need another web server in adition to node's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A front-end Nginx would be more efficient at serving static assets.

A front-end Nginx would also be useful if you wanted to run multiple backend servers, like Node.js combined with Apache/PHP where Node.js serves some routes and Apache/PHP serves other routes.

Comment: would having more than 1 web server such as `node.js` + `apache/php` scale well? or does that not make a difference?

Comment: @tq Static assets are things like (static) HTML pages or images. Things that don't need to be pre-processed by the server.

Comment: Having a backend node.js and a backend apache/php could scale just fine so long as you configure it correctly.  If you're pushing that much traffic then you'd have separate servers for Nginx, Node.js and Apache.  So long as you develop your app to correctly scale in general then combining Nginx, Node.js and Apache isn't a problem.

Comment: if pages needed pre processing such as `post` or `get` variables or connection to `dB`, would you recommend not using `nginx`?

Comment: Nginx doesn't handle those requests directly.  It proxies them to your backend server.  You can run those requests through Nginx without issue to your backend servers.